# GSON not converting JSON array to Java object array in release mode

Tags: android, json, gson

I am using GSON library for a long time, but now I am facing a strange problem in my app at play store, that data is stops displaying in the List.
I am using GSON to convert JSON array to Java ArrayList. The strange behaviour is while I am running app in debug mode the GSON doing its job perfectly. But after creating a release APK GSON giving null value.

Comment: Please don't use GSON for large data its buggy! Rather then use to extend Serialisable on your java objec class.

Comment: @NickBapu Thanks for your reply. But It was working fine since 2-3 years on my app. But suddenly it stopped working. I want to know that is there any changes have been made in GSON library . ?

Comment: What if downgrade the library? And please describe a behaviour. What if use smaller arrays (less items, less fields in the item)?

Comment: @CoolMind thanks for suggestion. I think this may solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome. Also a problem may be in backend. They could change a model. So you should check your model classes (with sites like jsonschema2pojo.org or AS plugins). Also I should say that model classes should be excepted in `proguard-rules.pro` (-keep class com.package.data.network.model.** { *; }).

Comment: can you post your logcat then it will be helpful for us to answer your question.